# BACKUP and RESTORE MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, restore, phpmyadmin

I have very specific question.
I have seen the instructions on how to backup and restore mysql database using SSH but they barely explain the process when backing up on one server and restoring on another server.

What i need is backup the mysql database on server A and restore the mysql database on server B. How do i do this using SSH command line?

I have seen this http://www.ipragmatech.com/backup-restore-mysql but nothing on backing up and restoring on different servers.

Thanks.

Comment: What OS and what edition of MySQL please? Out of the box, MySQL doesn't have on-line consistent backups so the solution depends on a few things (for example, we use ZFS snapshots)

Answer (score 2):

As from your question if the scenario is like that.

**You are on your local machine and accessing the remote servers A and B.**

Process is simple

#### Step1 : Connect to server A where A is username of server

```
ssh A@192.168.9.214
```

#### Step2 : Generate the database dump of the server A as

```
mysqldump -uroot -proot  db1  > database_db1.sql
```

#### Step3 : Copy the dump on the server B using SCP as

```
scp database_db1.sql B@192.168.9.215:/home/user/Desktop
```

#### Step4 : Connect to the Server B as

```
ssh B@192.168.9.215
```

#### Step5 : Restore the copied dump here using mysql client utility

```
mysql -uroot -proot db < /home/user/Desktop/database_db1.sql
```